# Decomposing model volatility with respect to factor contributions

Tags: linear-model, factor-analysis, matrix, linear-algebra, derivative

Consider a linear model

$\textbf{y} = \textbf{x}\pmb{\beta} + \pmb{\varepsilon}$

with $\textbf{y}$ a $T \times 1$ vector of random variables, $\pmb{\beta}$ a $K \times 1$ vector and $\textbf{x}$ a $T \times K$ matrix of random variables and $\pmb{\varepsilon}$ is a $T \times 1$ vector. In other words, I have a $K$-factor model for $\textbf{y}$. $t$ denotes times, $k$ the number of the factor, hence the time-series of $\textbf{x}$ are oriented column-wise, $\textbf{x} = (\textbf{x}_1,...,\textbf{x}_K)$ and $\textbf{x}_1$ is a $T \times 1$ vector.

The model variance is

$\sigma_{\textbf{y}} = g(\textbf{x}) =  \sqrt{\pmb{\beta}' \pmb{\Sigma_x}\pmb{\beta} +  \sigma_{\varepsilon}} = \sqrt{\pmb{\beta}'\textbf{x}'\textbf{x} \pmb{\beta} +  \sigma_{\varepsilon}}$

if $\textbf{x}'\textbf{x}$ are de-meaned. Here $\pmb{\Sigma}_x$ denotes the variance covariance matrix of x.

My goal is to compute the marginal contribution that $\textbf{x}_1$ has on $\sigma_{\textbf{y}}$. It seems to me that $\sigma_{\textbf{y}}$ is a function $g(\textbf{x})$ homogeneous of degree 1. Hence, I can apply the Euler's theorem and expect that

$g(x) = \frac{d g(\textbf{x})}{d \textbf{x}}x$

I computed

$\frac{d g(\textbf{x})}{d \textbf{x}} = \frac{x\beta\beta'}{g(\textbf{x})}$

which ends up being a $T \times K$ matrix. Therefore, how can the dimensions in $g(\textbf{x}) = \frac{d g(x)}{d \textbf{x}}x$ conform again to a scalar like $\sigma_{\textbf{y}} = g(\textbf{x})$? What I am doing wrong? Should I be taking the derivative of $g(\textbf{x})$ with respect to a single $\textbf{x}_1$ instead? What is the best way to proceed in this case?